# Warning: NSBundle NSBundle (not yet loaded) was released too many times in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, runtime-error, breakpoints, nsbundle

I'm getting this error when I try to test my app. If I completely close the simulator and re-launch, I can get past it temporarily, but it always comes back after one or two launches. Does anyone know what this is or how to fix it?

> Warning: NSBundle NSBundle  (not yet loaded) was released too many times. For compatibility, it will not be deallocated, but this may change in the future. Set a breakpoint on __NSBundleOverreleased() to debug

Also, how would I set a breakpoint as suggested? I only know how to set breakpoints on specific lines of code.

Comment: You getting this error, when launching a same application or different application?.

Comment: I'm just working with one application.

Comment: go on iOS Simulator -> "Reset content and settings.." and now run it again..

Comment: Clearing derived data seems to have solved it. Thanks @amar. Please post as solution and I'll accept it.

Comment: did you empty the trash after deleting derived data mac has very poor refrencing :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear derived data.

The app state are stored there and at times it prevents changes from showing there effect etc.

If you do any major change its best to delete derived data