# How to set a breakpoint __NSBundleOverreleased() to debug?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging

I don't know why but I have this error

> Warning: NSBundle NSBundle
>    (loaded) was
>   released too many times. For compatibility, it will not be
>   deallocated, but this may change in the future. Set a breakpoint on
>   __NSBundleOverreleased() to debug

I have tried, according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20964798/1670830), to delete the DerivedData folder but it is not working.

[image]

So, I tried to set a breakpoint, but the error is still logged and the program nevers stops at the breakpoint.

Do you have any advice or recommandation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Leave off the parentheses, and it'll work.

Not certain about the leading underscores, but if you try creating a working breakpoint with NSLog, for example, the parentheses aren't included.